# CSS - Columns overlapping and doing weird things

Tags: html, css, overlap

I am trying to make a social media feed similar to how pinterest does theres. I am iterating through each post and creating a 'pin' for it. Inside the pin will be the post, along with the user's data.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="columns">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) {?>
    <div class="pin">
        <div class="userinfo">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/profilepictures/<?php echo $profilepicture . '?' . $servertime ?>" width="50px" height="50px" id="post_userpic">                          
            <?php echo $this->model_users->getUserData('username', 3); ?>
        </div>
        <p>
            <?php echo $post->post; ?>
        </p>
    </div>              
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png) ;
}

#wrapper {
width: 600px;
max-width: 1100px;
min-width: 800px;
margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
background: #FEFEFE;
border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
margin: 0 2px 15px;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
padding: 15px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
opacity: 1;

-webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease;
-o-transition: all .2s ease;
transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {

border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}
}

#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
opacity: 0.4;
}

.userinfo {
border: 1px blue solid;

}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

This is close, but the problem is that they are overlapping and not aligning them properly.

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? It was kind of working before I tried making all pins 300px, which is what I need. But even then it was very sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, if boxes have position: static or relative. By default boxes will be placed by some type of native html grid.
But from your example, i think your solution is jQuery library **Masonry**

Check this out, hoppe it helps - http://desandro.github.io/masonry/

Comment: False. Ive had this working using the following example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: My issue is that I am trying to change the design of the pins, to have profile pic, username, date posted, and then the post. I want them to have a static width(300px). That and rearranging the elements inside messed it up.

Comment: Can you make some jsfiddle example with your html layout, so i can take a look?

Comment: The code above should be sufficient, if you put those into files it should run

Comment: Could you please help me out here? This shouldnt need any javascript.

Comment: Yes, would you like to put in jsfiddle your html already rendered, i.e. without php (grab it from page source) and give me a link to check it, because it can be some problem in html, i'd like to see the problem. Or you can send me a link to your site, if it is in production

Comment: I just figured it out as you answered sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem was in the

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}
}
```

It was forcing 5 columns at 300px each, which is more than my screen can handle, I changed them to 3 and gave a min-width to the wrapper and it works great!